# iOS QuickLook QLPreviewController can it display slide number of Microsoft Powerpoint Presentation

Tags: ios, powerpoint, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to view Microsoft Powerpoint Presentation using QLPreviewController. I would like to know the Total number of slides and the current slide number which I am viewing from the ppt.

As well as is it possible to navigate to particular slide programatically in QLPreviewController?

Could someone provide me the functional code for me to understand it better?

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? Steve